# Drawing a graph in LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am totally new in LaTeX. I was trying to plot the attached [image: graph] in LaTeX using the [introduction](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Picture_environment), but got lost.

Can't figure out how to draw the arrows with text.

**My attempt**

```
    \documentclass{article}



    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning,decorations.markings,quotes}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
   dot/.style = {circle, draw, fill, inner sep = 2pt},
   dot1/.style = {circle, draw, fill, inner sep = 1pt},
   decoration = {
     markings,
     %mark = at position 0.5 with {\pgftransformscale{2}}
     },
   ]
   \node (gamma-a) [dot, "initial position"] {};
   \node (gamma-b) [above right = 2cm and 6 cm of gamma-a, dot] {};
   \node (gamma-c) [above right = 2.25cm and 6.5 cm of gamma-a, dot1] {};
   \node (gamma-d) [above right = 1.9cm and 5.75 cm of gamma-a, dot1] {};
   \node (gamma-e) [below right = -0.5cm and 6 cm of gamma-a, "$\varepsilon$-neighbourhood"] {};
   \node (gamma-f) [above right = 1.4cm and 7 cm of gamma-a, "destination"] {};
   \draw [postaction = {decorate}, line width = 1pt] (gamma-a)
     to [out = -30, in = 120] (gamma-b);
   \draw [color = green, dashed, postaction = {decorate}, line width = 1pt] (gamma-a)
     to [out = -5, in = 110] (gamma-c);
   \draw [color = blue, dashed, postaction = {decorate}, line width = 1pt] (gamma-a)
     to [out = -45, in = 150] (gamma-d);
   \draw [color = gray, dashed](gamma-b) circle (0.8cm);
\end{tikzpicture}



    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full code is:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
   dot/.style = {circle, draw, fill, inner sep = 2pt},
   dot1/.style = {circle, draw, fill, inner sep = 1pt},
   decoration = {
     markings, 
     },
   ]
   \node (gamma-a) [dot, "initial position"] {};
   \node (gamma-b) [above right = 2cm and 6 cm of gamma-a, dot] {};
   \node (gamma-c) [above right = 2.25cm and 6.5 cm of gamma-a, dot1] {};
   \node (gamma-d) [above right = 1.9cm and 5.75 cm of gamma-a, dot1] {};
   \node (gamma-e) [below right = -0.75cm and 6 cm of gamma-a, "$\varepsilon$-neighbourhood"] {};
   \node (gamma-f) [above right = 1.4cm and 7 cm of gamma-a, "destination"] {};
   \node (gamma-g) [above right = 1.25cm and 1.5 cm of gamma-a, "exact controllable"] {};
   \node (gamma-e) [above right = 3.25cm and 4.75cm of gamma-a, "approximate controllable"] {};
   \draw [postaction = {decorate}, line width = 1pt] (gamma-a)
     to [out = -30, in = 120] (gamma-b);
   \draw [color = green, dashed, postaction = {decorate}, line width = 1pt] (gamma-a)
     to [out = -5, in = 110] (gamma-c);
   \draw [color = blue, dashed, postaction = {decorate}, line width = 1pt] (gamma-a)
     to [out = -45, in = 150] (gamma-d);
   \draw [color = gray, thick, dashed](gamma-b) circle (0.8cm);
   \draw[-Latex] (1.51,0)--(2,1.5) node[right]{};
   \draw[-Latex] (4.91,2.25)--(4.5,3.5) node[right]{};
   \draw[-Latex] (5.52,3.1)--(5.1,3.5) node[right]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Thank you for your attention!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

probably this is not the best solution but it offers a lot of flexibility. So, I suggest removing the text on nodes creation, as:

```
\node (gamma-a) [dot] {};
```

Then, after all the nodes are placed, you could draw the arrows as you like using the nodes as starting coordinates.

```
\draw[->]  (gamma-a) -- ++(-1,-1) coordinate(ref-a);
```

Last, using the arrow end coordinate (ref-a), you can place the text where you prefer.

```
\draw (ref-a) ++(-0.5,-0.5) node[]{inital position};
```

Hope, it is useful.